# Javascript I need help removing div inside another div

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to delete a div  that I created with insertAdjacentHTML.

The text on the page alternates between Hello and Test at random. When Hello is displayed a timer appears. I want to delete the clock div when it switches back to Test. Here's my code.

```html
<div class="message">Hello</div>
<div class="message">Test</div>
```

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('.message')].forEach(div => {

  if (div.textContent.includes("Hello") && !div.classList.contains('clock')) {
    div.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', "<div class=\"clock\"  data-sec=\"0\">00:00</div>");
    // This right here ^^ I want to delete this div when the text switches back to Test and redisplay when it goes back to Hello
  }

  if (!div.textContent.includes("Hello")) {
    //help me delete the just the clock only in the div that changes from Hello to test
    div.parentNode.removeChild(div.firstChild);
  }
  
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/073qfxsv/

Comment: It is an incomplete code, How are you switching between `Hello` div and `Test` div. It would be easier to understand if you could add more code...

Comment: The problem is, that `div` is the parent of the clock. Take a reference to the clock and remove it:  `div.removeChild(div.querySelector('.clock'));`.

Comment: or just `div.querySelector('.clock').remove()` ?